# Does Docker automatically update the image when I start my docker container

Tags: docker

If I start a Docker container based on `node:latest` and later on a new version of node becomes available, do I have to manually pull the newer node docker image or will Docker automatically pull the newer version of node the next time I use `docker start mynodeapp` ?

If Docker does not pull the newer image of node the next time I start my container, how do I keep my docker container updated with the latest version of node whenever it becomes available?

Comment: you have to build the image again. simply running the container wont update the node image

Comment: Even if you pull the image, `docker start` will reuse the old container based on the old image.  There's never really a reason to do this, though; I always use `docker run` and almost never `docker start` (and `docker stop` only on the way to `docker rm`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`docker start` (to start a stopped container)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/start/) cannot update the image as the container already exists based on the image when it was created.

But [`docker run` (to create a new container)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/) has an option `--pull=always` to force a `docker pull` and be sure to use an up-to-date version of the image.

Comment: Do you know what the rules for pulling a new `latest` image on a `docker run`command are if you don't specify the `--pull` option?

Comment: "If an image with that name already exists locally, use it without checking anywhere else."